# How would a breaking point for cost of living crisis look like?

Tags: europe, housing

Most European countries currently are (apparently) going throgh a massive cost of living crisis, where rents and cost of homes are skyrocketing and people are forced to pay significantly larger proportion of their wages for their home.

My question is - how far can this situation deteriorate? Have we seen similar situations in recent history and how were they resolved? How does a breaking point of such a crisis look like in a country and how does it affect citizens and their quality of life, short-term and long-term?

Comment: What do you mean by "breaking point"? Switching the political party in the government? Chosing a radical party? Riots in the streets? Destruction of the government and establishment of comunes?

Comment: @SJuan76 I don't know - that's the meat of the question. How does a breaking point look like?

Comment: It's just not a precisely defined term, you can only describe it in terms of other imprecise language:  it's when normal policies can no longer resolve the situation... But what is a "normal" policy?

Comment: A breaking point might be when prices are forced to readjust downwards by lack of demand and a recognition by investors - and in that I include individuals - that further gains are unlikely.  I don't know if one can generalize about Europe, but Canadian housing costs have far outstripped income gains and are at a historical anomalous high wrt income.  Lowering prices however would play havoc with people's savings.  How such a readjustment would play out is unclear, but Japan's 90s crisis makes for an unpleasant indicator:  gone far enough, there are no easy fixes for a government to deploy.

Comment: Still, this question is essentially inviting speculation as to what form a crisis might take, if it happened, so I am unsure that it is answerable.  Ask 2 economists and you'd probably get 3 opinions.  Large scale financing of housing using long term mortages at extremely low rates, along with highly restrictive planning regulations, with over-indebted countries, just hasn't been tried out that much before.

Comment: This question needs more details or clarity. How far can this situation deteriorate without X? What is a breaking point? It's not clear what situation this question is concerned with? People starving in masses maybe or something else?

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica "How such a readjustment would play out is unclear" Why? Build more houses in Canada and the market will solve the situation by itself. There is no guarantee that house prices always have to rise (although typically they do).

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution No, it is not as simple as that.  If the market takes care of the situation, lower prices (more supply) means lowering equity for existing home owners.  That's not a step the government will take lightly, being electoral suicide.  I think the National Post had an article about that - that there was no way the Canadian government would *intentionally* bring down prices by a large margin - about a year ago.  Can't find it now.

Comment: Pethaps belongs to History SE

Comment: Additionally, this Q may confuse some issues. I know of some European countries where food prices doubled compared to 2020, but rents have barely moved in comparison (mkay, maybe 20%). Even in the Euro area, where effects have been less spectacular, food has been the main driver of inflation lately https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/economic-bulletin/focus/2022/html/ebbox202204_06/ecb.ebbox202204_06.en_img0.png?394b174498f8fa6684e1093fb48a3c6d

Comment: Indirectly that's driven by energy costs and related/derived products "Global fertiliser prices also increased from already elevated levels, resulting in prices almost 200% higher than two years ago."

Comment: I see that Slovenia is experiencing some housing costs pressures, on the order of 15% y-o-y. I'm not sure if the rest of Europe is seeing similar rises. In fact the answer is no, EU-wide the increase has been an order of magnitude less https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/documents/2995521/16324891/2-04042023-BP-EN.pdf/70de4e2a-647a-b691-4400-766851c16482 So you're really confusing multiple issues here: what's usually call a cost-of-living crisis, local/Slovenian vs European situation, etc.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica "no way the Canadian government would intentionally bring down prices" That's how different the world can be. Where I live all kinds of interventions are discussed regularly, not limited to tax cuts for land buyers, subsidies for families, speeded up permissions or higher subsidies for the building of affordable low rent housing. Mostly it's not having a big effect, and always there is less money than what is expected to be needed, but if this is no intervention that potentially hurts existing property owners than I don't know what is.

Comment: As for the housing bubbles in some EE markets, if that's what they are, you don't have to look too far back, only circa 2008. OTOH one would expect hosing prices in the Euro area to converge somewhat over time. So long-term rises in EE and decreases in WE, as we've seen this year (according to the ECB) are pretty normal.